# Call vCenter 6.5 REST API with vcsim simulator

Tags: rest, simulator, vcenter

Probably is a silly question but how can I call vCenter 6.5 REST API with vcsim simulator?

I've not vCenter but I've install vcsim and govc from github, they works but no REST response. I've try several times.

vcsim should answer the call:

```
curl -sk https://user:pass@127.0.0.1:8989/[resource path]
```

but answer only:

```
curl -sk https://user:pass@127.0.0.1:8989/about
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks